# Component-based logging with logback (or: intercept foreign log messages)

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm looking for a way to define transitive log message routing. Let's say we have an application called poly with these packages:

```
com.mycompany.server-common
com.mycompany.communication
com.mycompany.webservice
```

server-common is used by both of the 2 others. All 3 use org.hibernate as well.

Now, I like to have 1 logfile for the webservice component with all messages from com.mycompany.webservice and with those messages from com.mycompany.server-common and org.hibernate that were initiated by the webservice. And then, another coresponding file for the communication package.

My application is a war file running in tomcat, where all components run in 1 context (it comes in 1 war file). I already defined the multiple log files, but they naturally only log that what i defined statically, there is no transitive inclusion.

I would be very interested in ideas how I could achieve the desired behaviour. I already thought about using the [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) for that, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.
Another idea was to separate the contexts, but I think in the current project state this will be hard and it does not offer the flexibility I hope for.

Any hints or discussions are appreciated.

Comment: An NDC or MDC is the simplest approach, what's your concern with either?

Comment: @DaveNewton just didn't use them yet, so I wanted some more experience-based opinions

Comment: They're handy for stuff like this, although I've often done some customization on the output format to be more "normalized", like putting a user entry first, or a component first, etc. depending on needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an MDC key when webservice starts serving a request and clear the MDC key at the end of the request, SiftingAppender will do what you are asking. Shout on the logback-user mailing list if you run into difficulties.